# C program to extract TLS record layer

Tags: ssl, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump, payload

I am trying to parse a pcap to get the packet bytes of only the TLS Record Layer in the payload.
In my following code I have managed to get only the tcp protocol bytes from the payload which contains the TLS Record Layer. I want to further extract only the TLS Record Layer bytes from this.
Could you tell me how I can modify my code to extract only that part of the payload?

```
void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet){
    static int count = 1;                   /* packet counter */

    /* declare pointers to packet headers */
    const struct ether_header *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
    const struct ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
    const struct tcphdr *tcp;            /* The TCP header */

    const struct sniff_udp *udp;        /* The UDP header */
    const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */

    int size_ip;
    int size_tcp;
    int size_udp;
    int size_payload;

    printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
    count++;

    /* define ethernet header */
    

    ethernet = (struct ether_header*)(packet);
    /* define/compute ip header offset */


    ip = (struct ip*)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header));

    
    size_ip = sizeof(struct ip);
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        //printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }

    /* print source and destination IP addresses */
    printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
    printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));

    /* determine protocol */
    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_IP:
            printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
            return;
     }

    /*
     *  OK, this packet is TCP.
     */

    /* define/compute tcp header offset */
    if(ip->ip_p == IPPROTO_TCP)
    {
        
        tcp = (struct tcphdr *)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct ip));
        
        size_tcp = sizeof(struct tcphdr);

        

        printf("   Src port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_sport));
        printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_dport));
        int sport = ntohs(tcp->th_sport);
        int dport = ntohs(tcp->th_dport);

        /* define/compute tcp payload (segment) offset */
        

        payload = (u_char *)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));

        /* compute tcp payload (segment) size */
        

        size_payload = header->len - (sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));
        /*
         * Print payload data; it might be binary, so don't just
         * treat it as a string.
         */
        if (size_payload > 0) {
            printf("   Payload (%d bytes):\n", size_payload);
            print_payload(payload, size_payload);

      //if ((sport == 80) || (dport == 80))
            //{
                // printf("   HTTP prase:\n");
                // prase_http(payload, size_payload);
            //}
            if(sport == 443 || dport == 443)
            {
                // printf("   SSL/TLS prase:\n");
                //prase_ssl_tls(payload, size_payload);
          //printf("%u",payload);
         // print_payload(payload, size_payload);
          parser(payload,size_payload);

            }
        }
    }

    /* UDP */
    else if(ip->ip_p == IPPROTO_UDP)
    {
        udp = (struct sniff_udp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
        size_udp = 8;
        printf("   Src port: %d\n", ntohs(udp->uh_sport));
        printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(udp->uh_dport));
        int sport = ntohs(udp->uh_sport);
        int dport = ntohs(udp->uh_dport);

        payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_udp);

        size_payload = ntohs(ip->ip_len) - (size_ip + size_udp);

        if (size_payload > 0) {
            //printf("   Payload (%d bytes:)\n", size_payload);

            if(sport == 53 || dport == 53)
            {
                // printf("   DNS prase:\n");
                // prase_dns(payload, size_payload);
            }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

This is the got_packet function passed as argument to pcap_loop which is part of <pcap.h> .All reference structures are used from
<arpa/inet.h>,<net/ethernet.h>,<netinet/ip.h>,<netinet/tcp.h>

I am looking to extract this part of the packet(image link attached):
[Screenshot from wireshark as to what I wish to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYZKW.png)

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Please add a pcap file, and the expected output. Plus provide a minimal compiling code (remove the commented code, provide a main, etc/

Comment: I have remodified question and added screenshot of output required.Hope it is fine now